# Is "electric" or "grass" better type advantage over "water"?

Tags: pokemon-go

When I fight Water-type Pokemon (Vaporeon) in gyms, I can't decide whether to use a Grass-type Pokemon (Exeggutor) or Electric-type Pokemon (Jolteon). Both are very effective.

Even though Jolteon has lower HP for similar CP, if there are Dragon-type Pokemon in the rest of the gym, I choose Jolteon, but only if Jolteon has Thunder or Thunderbolt. Otherwise, I use Exeggutor. Should I change that policy?

Comment: This is really up to personal preference, and what each individual has to combat the gym.

Comment: I think the primary question can be quantitatively analyzed.  If considering only Vaporeon, then Exeggutor has better overall base stats and attack damage per second (with best move set) than Jolteon.  If considering multiple defenders, then the analysis is longer than a comment.

Comment: I think this is an answerable, strategy-based question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a reason to change up what you're doing.

Pokemon Go, unlike the more traditional Pokemon games, don't really allow for the deeper more intricate combat that would really make your Jolteon vs Exeggutor choice matter. For Go, if both Pokemon are type effective then you should choose based on whichever one has the highest HP and or CP.

That being said, if all the other Pokemon in the gym are dragon types, just remember that dragons resist both grass and electric attacks so if you have something to deal with them like a Dewgong or some other ice type, that would probably be best. I would avoid using a dragon of your own unless you're good at dodging (and if dodging isn't broken as I know some people have had real issues with that mechanic).